# Dropdown to show all directories

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, nested

I would like to implement a php form that will have three dropdown menus. The first dropdown should display all the directories a given path. After selecting a directory of the first dropdown, the second dropdown should appear containing its sub-directories. Finally, the third dropdown, should appear containing all the subdirectories of the second dropdown. All directories and sub-directories contain elements.

I have implemented the first dropdown but I am not able to do so for the second and third.

Could you help me please?

Thank you in advance.

What I have done is:

```
<select name="s1" id="client" onChange="showSelected(this.value)">
      <option value="" selected="selected">Select client</option>

<?php
    if (chdir("/home/clients" )) {
       $dirs = glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
       foreach($dirs as $val){
          echo '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$val."</option>\n";
       }        
    }
?>

</select>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function showSelected(val){
        document.getElementById
('selectedResult').innerHTML = "Client is : " + val;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `scandir()`? It lists all directories from a given path, and if you select the directory, you can use some `$.ajax()` to get the subdirectories of the directory. http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

EDIT: Forgot to mention `scandir()` returns an array of the directories so you can foreach it. You can skip files like this:

```
<?php
function getDirs($path){
    $contents=scandir($path);
    $dirs = array();
    foreach($contents as $content){
        if(!is_file($content)){
            $dirs[] = $content;
        }
    }
    return $dirs;
}
?>
<select>
<?php $my_dir = "/home/www/"; ?>
<?php foreach(getDirs($my_dir) as $dir){echo '<option class="'.$my_dir.'">'. $dir . '</option>';} /*now you have the directories listed into a dropdown list*/ ?>

</select>
```

In the javascript part, I have ideas but I don't have time to test them. I hope at least you got the basics of programming. Good luck!

Comment: Hi,
thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I am new in php etc and not able to understand your suggestions. I would appreciate any more help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a PHP function with a parameter is parent dir

```
function getDir($parent_dir = '/home/clients'){
    $html = '<select name="s1" id="client" onChange="showSelected(this.value)">';
    $html .= '<option value="" selected="selected">Select client</option>';

    if (chdir($parent_dir)) {
       $dirs = glob('*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
       foreach($dirs as $val){
          $html .= '<option value="'.$val.'">'.$val.'</option>';
       }        
    }
    return $html;
}
```

Then using ajax call to this php function with selected value on select box and show on browser.

Comment: Hi,
thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, I am new in php, ajax etc and not able to understand your suggestions. I would appreciate any more help.
Thank you!